# The smallest $\epsilon>0$ that allows componentwise relative backward error

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Theorem: The smallest $\epsilon>0$ such that $\exists|\delta A|\leq\epsilon|A|$ and $\exists|\delta b|\leq\epsilon|b|$ satisfying $(A+\delta A)\hat{x}=b+\delta b$ is $\epsilon=\max_i\frac{|r_i|}{(|A|\cdot|\hat{x}|+|b|)_i}$ for residual $r=A\hat{x}-b$

I'm having trouble formulating a proof for this one, some hints would be nice to get me started. I guess where I'm having trouble conceptually is that it's the smallest $\epsilon>0$. Plugging in values didn't do much. I believe the condition number might have something to do here

Comment: What are the absolute values in the denominator?

Comment: arbitrary norms

Comment: Is $|A|$ induced by the vector norms? And is the norm on $b$ the same as the norm on $\hat{x}$?

Comment: That's a negative.

Comment: In $|δA|≤ϵ|A|$, is this in matrix norm or the component-wise absolute values? The question arises because in $(|A|⋅|\hat x|+|b|)_i$ you perform matrix-vector operations after the "absolute value" operation.

Comment: https://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/narep/narep173.pdf

This is the only proof I found online, top of page 5. It makes sense except when it came to the use of diagonal matrix D

Comment: but to answer your question it's in componentwise absolute value